# Usage of "вот только"

Tags: словоупотребление

In this example:

> **Вот только** дай мне закончить школу, и я сразу же от вас уеду и буду
>   жить, как мне хочется.

Does вот только mean the same as как только, perhaps with a more emotional bent? Can it be used in a situation where the speaker isn't necessarily upset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They differ.

**`как только`** is a conjunction which can introduce subordinate clause of timing, translated `as soon as`, `right after`

**`вот только`** can't function like that, it can be translated as **`just`** or **`simply`** and **`вот`** is added for emphasis but can be omitted

So this sentence in English should read something like

> Just let me graduate (first), OK, and I'll leave you right away....
>
> OR
>
> Just wait till after I graduate, OK, ....

It can be used in contexts where it doesn't express displeasure of the speaker, in these cases it imparts the statement a tenor of promise or prediction i guess.

`вот только` too can be translated `as soon as` but in Russian it's not a full synonym of `как только` and it only can introduce first clause in a compound sentence.

> Когда школа я не болею, а **вот только** начнется лето, (и) я сразу же заболею

Rehashing the sentence by swapping clauses to read

> *Когда школа я не болею, но я сразу же заболею, **вот только** начнется лето*

**doesn't** sound idiomatic, unlike it would do with the conjunction `как только`

In this function `вот только` in one clause is often (or perhaps always) coupled with adverbs either of immediacy (`сразу (же)`, `тут же`, `тотчас`) or surety (`обязательно`, `непременно`) in the next clause and requires verbs in future tense in perfective aspect in both

> вот только ...., (и) `сразу/тут же` / `обязательно`....

Depending on the context either part of `вот только` can be omitted.

Comment: in the sentence of the OP they are not synonymous, in other contexts, showcased in the reply they can be partly synonymous (i've corrected myself), in particular you can't use idiomatically `вот только` with verbs past tense, and they differ in their syntactical usage

Comment: Баян, ¿is this possibly related to another curious usage of вот that I recently found: Ты думаешь, что твой сын плохо себя ведет? Ты еще погоди. Вот станет он подростком, ты его вообще не узнаешь.

Comment: @CocoPop yes, this is similar, however `только` is incompatible with this construction, basically it doesn't convey the connotation of immediate and certain causality, but does that of prediction.